# Can't set tab icon

Tags: html

I'm trying to set the tab icon for a html page. I'm running on a ubuntu 20 machine.

My current directory looks like this:

```
ask@Garsy:~/Notes/html$ tree
.
├── finger.ico
└── html.html
```

And my html looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <link rel="icon" href="/finger.ico">
<h1>My First Heading</h1>
<p>My first paragraph.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

When I open the html file in the browser, there's no header icon. It does'nt work if I provide the absolute path either.

How do I get an actual icon displayed?

Comment: IMO, `<head>` should contain the [favicon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon#How_to_use) reference.

Comment: If you name it favicon.ico and put it in your root folder, the browser will find it automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a good idea to have it in the head section of the doc.
The name of the file should also be favicon.ico to tell the browser to use it. But if you want to name it anyway

This should work:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="icon" href="finger.ico">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>My First Heading</h1>
    <p>My first paragraph.</p>
</body>
</html>
```